# How do I clear space on my main system drive on a Linux CentOS system?

Tags: linux, centos

Sorry if this sounds dumb, but I'm not sure what to do.

I've got an Amazon EC2 instance with a completely full Ephemeral drive ( the main drive with all the system files ).  Almost all the directories where I've installed things like Apache, MySQL, Sphinx, my applications, etc. are on a separate physical drive and have symlinks from the ephemeral drive.  As far as I am aware, none of thier data or logs write to the ephemeral drive, so I'm not sure what happened to the space.

Obviously lots of system stuff is still on the ephemeral drive, but I'm not sure how to clear things off to make space.  My best guess is that amazon filled the drive when it did some auto updates to the system.  I'm trying to install some new packages, and update all my system packages via YUM, but the drive has no space.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works great.  Can take a few minutes on bigger drives ( over a few hundred GB ):

```
find /directory/to/scan/ -type f -exec du -a {} + | sort -n -r | less
```

The output will be the biggest files first.  You can page through the results with normal "less" commands ... space bar ( next page ) and b ( previous page ).

Answer (score 16):

```
du --max-depth=1 -h /
```

where `/` can be any directory starting from root will show you the size in human readable form (-h) without further recursing further down.

Once you find something big that you want to remove you can do it via

```
rm <thing you want to remove>
```

this accepts shell expansion, so for instance to remove all mp3 files:

```
rm *.mp3
```

if it's a directory then you need to add `-r`

```
rm -r /dir/to/remove
```

to protect yourself it would be advisable to add the `-i` switch to every `rm` call, this forces you to acknowledge that you want the files removed.

if there are a lot of readonly files you want to remove then you could add the `-f` switch to force deletion, be very careful with this.

Be careful that `rm` accepts multiple parameters so when you specify an absolute path make sure to do it within quotes or not to have any spaces, especially should you execute it as `root` and `super` especially with the `-r` and `-f` options. (otherwise you'll join the group of people that did `rm -rf / some/directory/*` and killed their `/` inadvertantly)

If you just want to look for big files and delete those then you could also use `find`

```
find / -type f -size +100M
```

would search for files only (`-type f`) with a size > 100MB (`-size +100M`)

subsequently you could use the same command to delete them.

```
find / -type f -size +100M -exec rm \{\} \;
```

`-exec` executes a program which gets passed the file or folder it has found ( `\{\}` ), needs to be terminated with `\;`

don't forget you could add `-i` to `rm` to approve or disapprove a deletion.

Comment: When you really have no clue where the file may be hiding, I find running this command ( `du --max-depth=1 -h ./` ) in the following folders almost always helps track down the culprit: /etc, /local, /sys, or /var.

Comment: Start with /var/cache/yum/*  if you're using an amazon EC2 - issuing a simple : sudo yum clean all   can clear up some breathing room time for further investigation.  also check out the maillogs - AWS save a month by default, but they can get rather large if you have a lot of cron jobs that echo output (it gets sent to user mail spool by default).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unix disk utility command `du` to see what's taking up all the space for starters.

Comment: Thank you. This quickly helped me find my HTTPD logs that I thought I  was writing somewhere else.  The old logs are taking up about 5GB of space in /var/log/httpd.