# How to free up space on centos server

Tags: linux, centos, space

I'm getting daily warning that my VPS server space is getting full. I have deleted old kernals, cleaned up install files and reduced the amount of backup stored. I'm not really sure what else I can delete?

I run the command:

```
du --max-depth=1 -h /

0       /dev
16K     /lost+found
1.6G    /var
75M     /opt
89M     /run
2.8G    /backup
38M     /etc
4.0K    /cd
4.0K    /srv
4.0K    /media
7.4G    /usr
2.6M    /tmp
0       /sys
179M    /boot
61M     /root
4.0K    /mnt
149G    /home
```

I also run the command:

```
df -l

Filesystem              1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  49066108 43581052   3396348  93% /
devtmpfs                  2009504        0   2009504   0% /dev
tmpfs                     2019500        0   2019500   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     2019500    90696   1928804   5% /run
tmpfs                     2019500        0   2019500   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                  463826   185067    250292  43% /boot
/dev/loop0                1948752     5624   1842472   1% /tmp
tmpfs                      403900        0    403900   0% /run/user/0
```

I have about 10 websites running on this VPS and I also deleted any backups stored within their respective accounts. Is there anything else here I can get rid of that I don't need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a bit of search here I found an answer from [How do I clear space on my main system drive on a Linux CentOS system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316664/how-do-i-clear-space-on-my-main-system-drive-on-a-linux-centos-system) that worked for me:

If you just want to look for big files and delete those then you could also use find

```
find / -type f -size +100M
would search for files only (-type f) with a size > 100MB (-size +100M)
```

subsequently you could use the same command to delete them.

```
find / -type f -size +100M -exec rm \{\} \;
```

-exec executes a program which gets passed the file or folder it has found ( {} ), needs to be terminated with \;

don't forget you could add -i to rm to approve or disapprove a deletion.